# What does "ambient atmosphere of 20 mu" mean?

Tags: pressure

I've read through a publication from 1960 which discusses oxygen annealing. It shows a the following graph. What does the "ambient atmosphere of XY mu" mean?
What is a mu atmosphere?

[image]
taken from: Residual resistance of copper annealed in an O2 atmosphere, R.L. Dolecek

Comment: I'd guess it is $ 20 \mu $ in some units they have used. Please provide a FULL source of the figure.

Answer (score 5):

The micron used in this way is a unit of pressure.  It's short hand for "micron of mercury".   It's the pressure that causes the column of mercury in a mercury manometer (pressure gauge) to rise one micro meter.   One Torr is one millimeter of mercury, and atmospheric pressure is 760 Torr.

1 $\mu$ = 0.133 Pa.